# How to display row data in separate column in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I m having the data like this...

[image: sample data]

```
with cte as
(select    *, rn = row_number() over (partition by empid order by trtime)
 from [10.xx.xx.xx].[dbName].dbo.[tableName] where empid='00ec2137' and    trdate='01/13/2014'
)
select    i.empid,i.trdate, i.trtime InTime, o.trtime OutTime
from    cte i
 inner join cte o    on    i.empid    = o.empid
             and    i.rn     = o.rn - 1

where i.InOUt    = 1
and    o.InOUt = 2
order by i.empid,i.rn
```

InOut 1 - "In timing" and 2 - "out timing". I want the data to be ordered like In Timing and Out Timing in a separate column. I m using the above query in SQL 2012 to display the data like below

**Getting Output**
[image: Getting Output]

**Expected Output**
[image: Requested Image]

In the output it displayed the first two rows only. As there is no Out timing 2 in third row, third row is not displayed. Please suggest me how to correct the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple I got this by modifying the inner join into left join and removed  o.InOUt = 2 in where condtion

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the where clause. Try this where clause instead:

```
where (i.InOUt    = 1)
and    (o.InOUt = 2 or o.InOUt is null)
```

this will bring when the user has logged out or still logged in.